# Use THC hydra to make dictionary attack on localhost

Tags: penetration-test, brute-force, hydra

I have programmed a log in in my webpage and now I want to test it against a dictionary attack. I am using Apache and my website is not online so to access it I connect to localhost/website In hydra I am using the command

`hydra -l username -P passList.txt localhost/website http-post-form "/logIn.php:user=^USER^&pass=^PASS:forgot"`

But it terminates with error

`[DATA] attacking service http-post-form on port 80
[ERROR] could not resolve address: localhost/website
0 of 1 target completed, 0 valid passwords found
[ERROR] 1 target did not resolve or could not be connected`

What could be the problem?

Comment: There are a number of places to look for the answer that might give you clues as to what is going wrong. What happens if you visit localhost/website in your browser? Can you ping it? Have you tried using 127.0.0.1/website? Have you tried looking at hydra -h more closely? Check /etc/hosts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the problem is here `localhost/website` This command should do the trick `hydra localhost http-post-form "/logIn.php:user=^USER^&pass=^PASS:forgot" -l username -P passList.txt`

Comment: or "/website/logIn.php", depending on the path.